# Can you explain how GROUP BY function works?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been getting trouble trying to use multiple functions to work in SQL. I wanted to make a RANK of bike travels or routes but the data only has start and stop datetime so I have to subtract them and then AVE the usual time and then RANK them. I usually get an error about using GROUP BY and I just end up copy-pasting solutions online. I want to understand clearly how it works.

I tried looking reading about its function but I just can't get it.

Comment: first make a database, make tables and add data, then run the queies and see what happens, then change the parameters and you see the different results, and then you should get the idea behind it

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate functions (min, max, avg, sum, etc) work on groups of data (though a group may be all your data). So this:

```
SELECT AVG(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Would give the average salary of all your employees e.g. $54,743.98

If you want to split your data into subsets, you can use a GROUP BY clause. If you do this then your SELECT clause must contain all the columns in your GROUP BY and and other columns must be part of an aggregate (most RDBMSs enforce this, MySQL is the only common one I know of that doesn’t necessarily) e.g.

```
SELECT JOB_LEVEL,
AVG(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY JOB_LEVEL;
```

e.g.

| JOB_LEVEL | AVG(SALARY) |
| --- | --- |
| JUNIOR | 24,426.78 |
| SENIOR | 53,654.38 |
| MGMT | 86,492.17 |

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks! You've been awesome. I can't upvote yet since I'm new to stack overflow but this really helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Group by basically allows you to put your data in buckets, and display **one row** per bucket:

| col1 | col2 | nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | ax | 3 |
| a | ay | 6 |
| a | ax | 1 |
| b | bx | 5 |
| b | by | 4 |

`group by col1`  will lead to following buckets:

rows of bucket 'a':

| col1 | col2 | nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | ax | 3 |
| a | ay | 6 |
| a | ax | 1 |

rows of bucket 'b':

| col1 | col2 | nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | bx | 5 |
| b | by | 4 |

But since a group by-statement will display only one row per bucket, you have to use aggregate functions to 'merge' the rows contained in a bucket into a single row.

```
select row1, sum(nb), listagg(col2, ',') from data group by row1;
```

will give you (oracle)

| col1 | sum(nb) | listagg(col2, ',') |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | ax,ay,az |
| b | 9 | bx,by |

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY statement groups rows that have the same values.
GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()) to group the result-set by one or more columns.
Example:

Here I have taken the DateTime difference as timeInMin for convenience.

```
CREATE TABLE info(
bike varchar(5),
timeInMin int

);

INSERT INTO info(bike, timeInMIn)
VALUES ('001', 15);

INSERT INTO info(bike, timeInMIn)
VALUES('002', 10);

INSERT INTO info(bike, timeInMIn)
VALUES ('001', 20);

INSERT INTO info(bike, timeInMIn)
VALUES('002', 5);

select * from info;
```

This gives the following results

```
  Bike  AVG(timeInMin)
  001          15
  002          10
  001          20
  002          5
```

Next we will rank the bikes using following query.

```
select bike, AVG(timeInMin) from info group by bike;
```

This gives the following results

```
Bike       AVG(timeInMin)   
  002         7.5            
  001         17.5
```

Here we grouped the results by bike. For that, we aggregated it using AVG(timeInMin). So, what happens is for the same bike, take all timeInMin values and then find the average of those. Then listed the results in ascending order

Does this help?
If you have more questions I am more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, let us suppose that there exists a weather database which contains a table of recorded temperatures for a particular location at given intervals each month:

```
weather=# select date, month, year, temp from weatherdata order by date desc limit 10;

        date         | month | year | temp  
---------------------+-------+------+-------
 2023-07-07 17:42:43 |     7 | 2023 | 26.70
 2023-07-06 15:40:54 |     7 | 2023 | 20.10
 2023-07-04 16:12:48 |     7 | 2023 | 18.30
 2023-07-04 02:10:17 |     7 | 2023 | 10.80
 2023-07-02 18:17:59 |     7 | 2023 | 18.70
 2023-06-30 22:03:30 |     6 | 2023 | 14.80
 2023-06-25 18:08:28 |     6 | 2023 | 24.80
 2023-06-25 02:29:24 |     6 | 2023 | 17.70
 2023-06-23 17:13:15 |     6 | 2023 | 23.10
 2023-06-21 00:31:57 |     6 | 2023 | 13.30
```

**Objective:** Use the GROUP BY statement to find the average temperature by month. This can be accomplished as follows:

```
weather=# select month, avg(temp) from weatherdata where year='2023' group by month order by month;
 month |         avg         
-------+---------------------
     1 |  5.5513513513513514
     2 |  8.4809523809523810
     3 |  8.4967741935483871
     4 | 12.4857142857142857
     5 | 23.5500000000000000
     6 | 23.5523809523809524
     7 | 18.9200000000000000
(7 rows)
```

**Result:** We now have a table which shows the average temperature in a month for the year 2023.